# Need help looping through captions attached to an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need to Create a for loop with a counter that goes from 0 to less the length of the captions array in increments of 1. With each iteration, add the following text to the value of the htmlCode variable:

```
<figure>
<img alt='' src='slidei.jpg' />
<figcaption>caption[i]</figcaption>
</figure>
```

where i is the value of the counter for that iteration and captions[i] is the corresponding element from the
captions array.
Im having issues getting through this and ive been stuck on it for days if anyone is able to help me

```
    let captions = new Array(14);
captions[0] = "International Space Station fourth expansion [2009]";
captions[1] = "Assembling the International Space Station [1998]";
captions[2] = "The Atlantis docks with the ISS [2001]";
captions[3] = "The Atlantis approaches the ISS [2000]";
captions[4] = "The Atlantis approaches the ISS [2000]";
captions[5] = "International Space Station over Earth [2002]";
captions[6] = "The International Space Station first expansion [2002]";
captions[7] = "Hurricane Ivan from the ISS [2008]";
captions[8] = "The Soyuz spacecraft approaches the ISS [2005]";
captions[9] = "The International Space Station from above [2006]";
captions[10] = "Maneuvering in space with the Canadarm2 [2006]";
captions[11] = "The International Space Station second expansion [2006]";
captions[12] = "The International Space Station third expansion [2007]";
captions[13] = "The ISS over the Ionian Sea [2007]";

var htmlCode = "";

for (let i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
  <figure>
    <img alt='' src='slidei.jpg' />
    <figcaption>htmlCode += captions[i]</figcaption>
  </figure>
}

document.getElementById(gallery).innerHTML = htmlCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two points need to pay attention:

1. Using `document.getElementById('gallery')` instead of `document.getElementById(gallery)`
2. You can use [Template_literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to store the interate values and finally assign it to `gallery` outside loop

```js
let captions = new Array(14);
captions[0] = "International Space Station fourth expansion [2009]";
captions[1] = "Assembling the International Space Station [1998]";
captions[2] = "The Atlantis docks with the ISS [2001]";
captions[3] = "The Atlantis approaches the ISS [2000]";
captions[4] = "The Atlantis approaches the ISS [2000]";
captions[5] = "International Space Station over Earth [2002]";
captions[6] = "The International Space Station first expansion [2002]";
captions[7] = "Hurricane Ivan from the ISS [2008]";
captions[8] = "The Soyuz spacecraft approaches the ISS [2005]";
captions[9] = "The International Space Station from above [2006]";
captions[10] = "Maneuvering in space with the Canadarm2 [2006]";
captions[11] = "The International Space Station second expansion [2006]";
captions[12] = "The International Space Station third expansion [2007]";
captions[13] = "The ISS over the Ionian Sea [2007]";

var htmlCode = "";

for (let i = 0; i < captions.length; i++) {
  htmlCode += `<figure>
    <img alt='' src='slidei.jpg' />
    <figcaption>htmlCode += `+captions[i]+`</figcaption>
  </figure>`
}

document.getElementById('gallery').innerHTML = htmlCode;
```

```html
<div id="gallery"></div>
```